# Using a generate with for loop in verilog

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to understand why we use generate in verilog along with a for loop.

Using a generate and for loop together:

```
reg [3:0] temp;
genvar i;
generate
for (i = 0; i < 3 ; i = i + 1) begin: 
    always @(posedge sysclk) begin
        temp[i] <= 1'b0;
    end
end
endgenerate
```

Using only for loop:

```
reg [3:0] temp;
genvar i;
always @(posedge sysclk) begin
  for (i = 0; i < 3 ; i = i + 1) begin: 
    temp[i] <= 1'b0;
    end
end
```

I'm considering the two snippets would basically produce the same result i.e. temp[0] to temp[10] equal to value 0. What is the difference/advantage we see by using a generate statement in this case ?

Comment: Have you tried compiling these snippets? The second one should be a syntax error. You can only put always inside for loop only if the for loop is inside generate!

Comment: @user1995025, `i` needs to be a `genvar`

Comment: @Ari: Thanks for clearing out the confusion for me. I understand the requirement for the generate now.

Comment: @Greg: I did declare `i` as a genvar in the first snippet.

Comment: @user1995025 it is a `integer` in the second snippet and needs to be `genvar` to be legal

Comment: @Greg I disagree `integer` is the correct use in the second example. [example on EDA playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/DVe), which does not compile if set to genvar. The second example as it currently stands is a basic iterator.

Answer (score 13):

In general, the main difference between generate for loop and regular for loop is that the generate for loop is generating an instance for each iteration. Meaning that in *your* example there will be 3 always blocks (as opposed to 1 block in the regular loop case).

A good example of code that **requires** generate for is:

```
module A();
..
endmodule;

module B();
parameter NUM_OF_A_MODULES = 2; // should be overriden from higher hierarchy
genvar i;
for (i=0 i<NUM_OF_A_MODULES; i=i+1) {
  A A_inst();
}
endmodule;
```

In this example a regular for cannot do the work of creating NUM_OF_A_MODULES instances.

In *your* example, you can acheive the required result in both ways. (as long as you fix some minor bugs :) )

Answer (score 7):

In the example without the `generate`, `i` should be a `genvar` not `integer`. Otherwise, both are valid depending on the version of the IEEE Std 1364 supported by your tool set. The generate construct was added in in IEEE Std 1364-2001 where the `generate`/`endgenerate` keywords are explicitly required. In IEEE Std 1364-2005 it became optional with the only requirement that if `generate` is used it must have a matching `endgenerate`.

When using IEEE Std 1364-2005 or SystemVerilog (IEEE Std 1800), it is a matter for coding style preference of implicit vs explicit declaration. Explicit does have the advantage of being backward comparability.

---

Generate blocks are useful when change the physical structure of then module via parameters. For example choosing negedge or posedge clock and only enabling one:

```
if ( param_use_pos == 1) begin : use_pos
  always @(posedge sysclk) begin
    ...
  end
end
else begin : use_neg
  always @(negedge sysclk) begin
     ...
  end
end
```

If you are not changing the physical structure, it is typically better to use for loops and if-else statements inside the always block. Both approaches can synthesize the same but when running RTL simulation the non-generate block approach will typically simulate faster. This is because simulators normally can process a single N-bit operation faster than N 1-bit operations. Again synthesis is the same result

```
// faster :: 1 always block, simulator can optimize the for loop
always @(posedge sysclk) begin 
  for (i = 0; i < 3 ; i = i + 1) begin
    temp[i] <= 1'b0;
  end
end

// slower :: creates 4 always blocks, harder for the simulator to optimize
genvar i;
generate // optional if > *-2001
for (i = 0; i < 3 ; i = i + 1) begin 
    always @(posedge sysclk) begin
        temp[i] <= 1'b0;
    end
end
endgenerate // match generate
```

Comment: I think an example which shows how generate can be used to create a parametrised number of instantiations, where as the for loop can just iterate over fixed hardware the difference between the two might be even clearer.

Answer (score 1):

`generate for` loops let you access (using hierarchical names) the internal signals of the **instances generated**. The regular `for` loop doesn't let you do that.

Otherwise, in principle, the loop unrolling happens for both (for synthesizable constructs, atleast).

Hence, for testbenches it may be more typical to use regular `for` loops, but for the design modules it may be more typical to use `generate for` loops.