# Verilog HDL syntax error near text “for”; expecting “endmodule”

Tags: verilog, quartus

```
 module alu(input logic [31:0] a, b,
              input logic [2:0] f,
             output logic [31:0] y,
             output logic zero);  

    wire [31:0] ANDed, ORed, SLT, sum, cout, bn;
    wire set_less;
    reg zero_detect;
    genvar i;

    //This segment will take 2s complement of B
    for(i = 0; i < 32; i = i+1) begin
     assign bn[i] = b[i] ^ f[2];
    end

    //This segment will compute the 32-bit addition
    assign sum[0] = (a[0] ^ bn[0]) ^ f[2];
    assign cout[0] =(a[0] & bn[0]) | ((a[0] ^ bn[0]) & f[2]);

    for(i = 1; i < 32; i = i +1) begin
     assign sum[i] = (a[i] ^ bn[i]) ^ cout[i-1];
     assign cout[i] = (a[i] & bn[i]) | ((a[i] ^ bn[i]) & cout[i-1]);
    end

    //This segment will complete the AND operation
    assign ANDed = a & bn;

    //This segment will complete the OR operation
    assign ORed = a | bn;

    //set less than, A < B then the first digit of the sum will be 1
    assign set_less = sum[31];
    assign SLT = {{31'b0000000000000000000000000000000}, set_less};

    //Set the zero flag if there aren't any 1's in the output
    assign zero = !(|y);

    //select the output based on the function input
    assign y = f[1] ? (f[0] ? SLT : sum )
                         : (f[0] ? ORed : ANDed);
    endmodule
```

> Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at alu.sv(15) near text:
>   "for";  expecting "endmodule". Check for and fix any syntax errors
>   that appear immediately before or at the specified keyword.
>
> Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at alu.sv(23) near text:
>   "for";  expecting "endmodule". Check for and fix any syntax errors
>   that appear immediately before or at the specified keyword.
>
> Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at alu.sv(26) near text:
>   "end";  expecting "endmodule". Check for and fix any syntax errors
>   that appear immediately before or at the specified keyword.
>
> Error (10112): Ignored design unit "alu" at alu.sv(4) due to previous
>   errors

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your syntax. perhaps there is a problem with the code that comes before the module

Comment: the question is which tool and which version of the tool  you are using. It might not support 'for' loops without `generate..endgeneerate` around `for` loops in your case.

Comment: Quartus Prime Version 17.1.0 Build 590 10/25/2017 SJ LITE EDITION

Comment: ModelSim - INTEL FPGA STARTER EDITION 10.5b
Revision: 2016.10
Date: Oct 5 2016

Answer (score -1):

genvar variable should only be used with generate block. Use for loop within generate-endgenerate block to get rid of errors.

Comment: Sorry. That is not true. In Verilog 2005 if was permitted to use a _genvar_ without a _generate_ statement.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor are you sure? as far as i know, this is true for 'system verilog' 2012

Comment: Yes. I teach Verilog. There's a slide about this on the Verilog course I teach.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor thanks, you were correct, i found it.

Comment: @vinayak See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25924620/2755607, and I suggest deleting this answer

Comment: So how would I go about fixing it?